# How to create a table from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can transfer an array with multiple variables into an HTML table using only javascript. My javascript code so far is rendering everything onto the page and I don't want the tags like  and such showing. The result should look something like this [[table_example_image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOfIA.png).

The instructions are:

Using JavaScript, iterate through the items in the array, and dynamically display the collection within a table under the  section of your webpage.

The entire table (including replacing any true/false text with actual images like in the example) and content should be generated and outputted with JavaScript.

Within the table, create a  element for each of the properties in the array collection (for example title, author, alreadyRead) - column count and text should be dynamically generated based on JavaScript, and not "hardcoded".

Create and append a  for each value
Use JavaScript to append and create the style rules for the table within the  section of the HTML document.

Any tips would be appreciated!

```
    var books = [
    {
        title: 'The Stranger',
        author: 'Albert Camus',
        alreadyRead: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Binging with Babish',
        author: 'Andrew Rea',
        alreadyRead: true
    },
    {
        title: 'You Suck at Cooking: The Absurdly Practical Guide to Sucking Slightly Less at Making Food: A Cookbook',
        author: 'You Suck at Cooking',
        alreadyRead: false
    }];

createTable();

function createTable() {
    var table = document.createElement("table");  //makes a table element for the page

    table += "<tr class='firstRow'><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Read?</th></tr>";  //adds the first row that contains the sections for the table

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)  //loops through the array 
    {
        //add info from the array into this
        table += "<tr><td>" + books[i].title + "</td><td>";
    }

    document.body.append(table);
}
```

Comment: What issue(s) are you having with the posted code?

Answer (score 3):

You're currently trying to add a string to an table object. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) page out.

```
function createTable() {

    var headers = ["Title", "Author", "Read?"];
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");  //makes a table element for the page
        
    for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = books[i].title;
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = books[i].author;
        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = books[i].alreadyRead;
    }

    var header = table.createTHead();
    var headerRow = header.insertRow(0);
    for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        headerRow.insertCell(i).innerHTML = headers[i];
    }

    document.body.append(table);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everybody on here has been giving me a ton of awesome tips and info, this is seriously awesome!

Answer (score 1):

To add stringified tags to parent tag,

parentTag.innerHTML = stringifiedTag;

Hope it's helpful.

```js
  var books = [
    {
        title: 'The Stranger',
        author: 'Albert Camus',
        alreadyRead: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Binging with Babish',
        author: 'Andrew Rea',
        alreadyRead: true
    },
    {
        title: 'You Suck at Cooking: The Absurdly Practical Guide to Sucking Slightly Less at Making Food: A Cookbook',
        author: 'You Suck at Cooking',
        alreadyRead: false
    }];

createTable();

function createTable() {
    var table = document.createElement("table");  //makes a table element for the page
    let innerT = "";
    
    innerT += "<tr class='firstRow'><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Read?</th></tr>";  //adds the first row that contains the sections for the table

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)  //loops through the array 
    {
        //add info from the array into this
        innerT += "<tr><td>" + books[i].title + "</td><td>";
    }
    table.innerHTML = innerT;
    
    document.body.append(table);
}
```

Comment: @DarwinWatterson You're welcome! If you think it's helpful then please select my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [**insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) not '**+=**'

example :

```js
       var books = [
        {
            title: 'The Stranger',
            author: 'Albert Camus',
            alreadyRead: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Binging with Babish',
            author: 'Andrew Rea',
            alreadyRead: true
        },
        {
            title: 'You Suck at Cooking: The Absurdly Practical Guide to Sucking Slightly Less at Making Food: A Cookbook',
            author: 'You Suck at Cooking',
            alreadyRead: false
        }];
    
    
    function createTable() {
        let table = document.createElement("table");  //makes a table element for the page
        
        table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<tr class='firstRow'><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Read?</th></tr>"); //adds the first row that contains the sections for the table
    
        for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)  //loops through the array 
        {
            //add info from the array into this
            table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<tr><td>" + books[i].title + "</td><td>");
        }
    
        document.body.append(table);
    }
    
    createTable();
```

Comment: @DarwinWatterson you're welcome , don't forget to read more about insertAdjacentHTML so helpful